# EasyMock verify parameter of mocked object

Tags: java, parameters, easymock, verify

I would like to verify if a parameter of a mocked object is correctly mapped (before the methodcall there is a mapping). 
I've created two objects, one of which has the expected values.
I expect the false one to fail, but somehow easymock does not verify if the parameter contains the expected values. How can I fix that?

Real class does:

```
public SomeObject methodname() {
    MyClass  parameter = mapper.map(source,Dest.class);
    serviceBeingMocked.doSomething(parameter); //<-- want to verify this parameter
}
```

Test

```
 MyClass correct = ...;
 correct.setA=a;
 correct.setB=b;

 expect(serviceBeingMocked(correct)).andReturn(iDontCare); //this should work



 MyClass false = ...;
 false.setA=eeeeeeeeeee;
 false.setB=ffffffffff;

 expect(serviceBeingMocked(false)).andReturn(iDontCare); // this test should fail
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Found the answer (using capture to record the paramter and test the values via assert)

Capture paramter = new Capitre();
expect(serviceBeingMocked(EasyMock.capture(parameter)));

assertEquals(parameter.getValue().getWhatever().equals(correct.getWhatever());

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please post an SSCCE, and explain what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Modified question and added example. hope that clarifies it.

Comment: It would be more clear if the name "false" were not used as a variable name as many people would assume that it refers to the primitive boolean literal "false" (I didn't even think it was legal to use this as a variable name since it is a reserved keyword.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this test is a test foe `methodname()`. And you would like to test that, given a source, the correct MyClass paremeter is created by the mapper, and passed to `serviceBeingMocked.doSomething()`.

So in fact, your unit test for `methodname()` actually tests the `mapper.map()` method. That's wrong. You should write a unit test for `mapper.map()` to test that. Once you've ensured that `mapper.map()` works as expected, you can test `methodname()` by mocking the `mapper.map()` method, and verify that the result of this mocked method is passed to the mocked service (although this test wouldn't add much value).

To be complete, if you really want to go your way and check the value passed to `serviceBeingMocked()`, then you should use a [capture](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/3.1/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#capture%28org.easymock.Capture%29).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just found out about capture myself, which is what I was looking for.